# How do I create a LINQ query to produce a unique list of objects from arrays inside object fields?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a series of file objects that have an array of signer objects as a field. For a package object, I need to include a single array of all the signer objects inside each file contained in a package.

Currently, I am using this code to achieve the same result, but think this can be simplified and improved using LINQ.

```
foreach(var file in files) {    
   holder.AddRange(file.signers); 
} 
holder.Select(x => x).Distinct();
```

Comment: change holder to hashset and use unionwith ?  files selectmany singers and distinct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SelectMany` to essentially flatten the signers in to a single list.

There's also no need to do `.Select(x => x)` it is essentially a no-op.

```cs
holder
  .AddRange(files.SelectMany(file => file.signers))
  .Distinct();
```

#### HashSet version

Using a HashSet as suggested by @Selvin as HashSets cannot contain duplicate entries and therefore no need for any equivalent to  `Distinct()`

```cs
// Earlier
HashSet<T> holder;

holder.UnionWith(files.SelectMany(file => file.signers));
```

Comment: This answer robust and also helped me.

Comment: Why not inline the HashSet method as `HashSet<T> holder = files.SelectMany(file => file.signers).ToHashSet();` ?

Comment: @Narish you could do if you don't care about any possible existing contents. We can't see where `holder` came from so I haven't assumed it's empty!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
files
 .Select(file => file.signers) //For each file in files return the file.signers prop
 .SelectMany(signers => signers) //Flatten the multiple enumerables of signer to one enumerable of strings
 .Distinct()
 .ToArray(); // Cast enumerable to Array
```

Comment: This won't include any items that already existed in `holders`. Also you don't need to do both `Select` and `SelectMany`, `SelectMany` on it's own is enough `.SelectMany(file => file.signers)`!

Comment: @phuzi is correct that you do not need the .select here.